# Jenkins: Maven Release on CVS Tag

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, release, cvs

I am trying to implement a maven release build on a specific cvs tag. Here is my workflow I'm trying to implement:

1. Jenkins builds a project every night.
2. Jenkins deploys the WAR on a internal testserver.
3. After some time I tag an specific tested nightly build in CVS.
4. Now I will run a maven release build on that specific tag to make sure that only tested changes are in this release and newer changes are irgnored.
5. The maven release plugin tags this version and deploys the WAR to an artifactory.

Is it somehow possible to make a maven release on a specific CVS tag/branch? Currently I am able to build specific tags/branches with jenkins and also execute a maven release build on this tag/branch. But when I check the tag of the release version it also contains newer changes which makes it unpossible to create hotfixes for this version or just checkout the correct source for a certain version. Another big problem is that the resulting artifact also contains all changes from the HEAD and not only from the selected tag/branch.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the tag in the CVS settings

[image: jenkins-cvs-settings]

Comment: I know this and I also created a parameterize job to pass a specific tag/branch. But the problem is that this not working in conjuction with a maven release build...

Comment: Ok, can you explain what "not working" means. Are you getting an error?

Comment: The problem is that the maven release plugin always uses the HEAD revision and not the tag/branch I define in the CVS konfiguration. Is it possible to say the maven release plugin to use a specific tag/branch? It seems that it always checks out the latest HEAD revision..